Some GUI's not opening when using remote desktop Ubuntu 24.04
When I try to open Files or Settings while connected via RDP, the windows never open. I have also tried to open 2 Java based GUI's, Pycharm being one of them, and the RDP connection crashes every time. I am unsure what could be causing this. Firefox will open and so will the terminal.
